# Connect to Neptune DB from Rest API .NET C#

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gremlin, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-neptune

I am trying to connect a .NET C# Service to my Neptune DB Instance. Through command lines, I am able to query the Database by connecting to an EC2 Instance and running a Gremlin client in that connection. I am now trying to establish a connection between my Rest API and the Neptune DB but I am failing to do so. I am able to connect to the EC2 Instance here

```
private SshClient ConnectToEC2()
    {
        string host = "12.345.678.99";
        string username = "ec2-user";
        string privateKeyFilePath = "C:\\Users\\my-user\\privatekey.pem";

        PrivateKeyFile privateKeyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(privateKeyFilePath);

        var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(
            host,
            username,
            new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username, privateKeyFile));

        var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
        
        client.Connect();

        return client;
    }
```

However, I don't want to create this SSH connection everytime I want to query the DB. I've also read about https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dbs-refarch-graph/tree/master/src/connecting-using-a-load-balancer#connecting-to-amazon-neptune-from-clients-outside-the-neptune-vpc-using-aws-network-load-balancer
to set up a Load Balancer to connect to Neptune. However, with my limited knowledge in AWS as well as Ports, can I get some code help/specific details on how to set this up?

I tried to create a Gremlin Client here after connecting to EC2 but I couldn't get it to work.

```
string gremlinHost = "localhost"; 
        int gremlinPort = 8182;
        var portForwarded = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", (uint)gremlinPort, gremlinHost, (uint)gremlinPort);
        client.AddForwardedPort(portForwarded);
        portForwarded.Start();
        var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer("localhost", (int)portForwarded.BoundPort, enableSsl: false);
        var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(gremlinServer);
        var remoteConnection = new DriverRemoteConnection(gremlinClient, "g");
        var g = Traversal().WithRemote(remoteConnection);
```

Any kind of help, no matter how small, is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon Neptune database cluster sits inside a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC). It is not exposed to the Public internet. To access it your code either has to also run inside the VPC (for example running on an EC2 instance in the same VPC), or your code has to be given access to the VPC. For dev/test, using an SSH tunnel where the EC2 instance acts as a bastion host is definitely one way to do it. If you want to run the code from outside of the VPC, perhaps from your development machine on your desk, you will need to provide a way for it to access the VPC. It could be via SSH tunnel, ALB, NLB, or one of many other ways.

The easiest way for dev/test is often the SSH tunnel. To create a tunnel you can use the `ssh` command usually (if your OS supports it) and would typically be a command such as:

```
ssh -i mykey.pem -N ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com -L 8182:my-cluster.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182
```

Once that tunnel is established you can connect from your client using the DNS name of the Neptune database. You also need to make sure there is an entry in your local hosts file that maps the Neptune cluster to localhost.

There are actually some quite good setup instructions here (only the SSH part is relevant): https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/tree/main/additional-databases/neptune

This is the sort of thing that is hard to explain in detail in a single SO Post answer as there are many options once you start looking at things like load balancers. If the SSH tunnel option can suffice for now the instructions above should get you going.

It might also be worth opening an AWS support case if you are able to so that someone could walk you through this on the phone.

Regardless, see if any of the above helps, and I'll keep an eye out for follow up questions.